Laravel 10: Save file outside the Laravel application in a directory
I attempted to set the directory in $outputPath to save the file outside of the Laravel application, specifically directly into the directory http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.
However, I encountered the following error:
copy(http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/ergebnis_16.04.2024_08-41-38.docx): Failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
My Code:
$timestamp = date('d.m.Y_H-i-s');

$templatePath = public_path('templates/su_temp_general.docx');
$outputPath = url('http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/ergebnis_' . $timestamp . '.docx');
$su = 1;
$mva_bam = 1000;
$description = "Testbeschreibung";
$date = date('d.m.Y');
$serialNo = '123456';
$material = 'Aluminium';
$workcenter = 'DR123';
$process = 'Testprozess';
$toolNo = '123456x';
$typeInvestigations = 'Testuntersuchung';

$template = new TemplateProcessor($templatePath);
$template->setValue('Su', $su);
$template->setValue('Mva_Bam', $mva_bam);
$template->setValue('Description', $description);
$template->setValue('Date', $date);
$template->setValue('PartNo', $partNo);
$template->setValue('SerialNo', $serialNo);
$template->setValue('Material', $material);
$template->setValue('Workcenter', $workcenter);
$template->setValue('Process', $process);
$template->setValue('ToolNo', $toolNo);
$template->setValue('TypeInvestigations', $typeInvestigations);
$template->setValue('Customer', $customer);

$template->saveAs($outputPath);

I tried both the URL and public_path, but unfortunately, without success.

"HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections" You cannot write to a file via http, use a filesystem path to write to

I have tried - $outputPath = url('127.0.0.1:8000/data/ergebnis_' . $timestamp . '.docx');  -Error : copy(http://127.0.0.1:8000/127.0.0.1:8000/data/ergebnis_16.04.2024_09-03-01.docx): Failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

You are doing something strange that no one can understand. Learn the basics of web before using Laravel.

That still is a URL. Use a filesystem path like /home/rayn/.. or C:\Downloads\... depending on your OS

Sorry I am a beginner

Being a beginner is nothing to be sorry for, we've all been there

Unfortunately this does not work either, I always get the same error message

Are you still using url() - because that will return a ... URL! Use something like $outputPath = 'C:\htdocs\ergebnis_' . $timestamp . '.docx'; Adjust C:\htdocs to the filesystem path

i have make a dd - resulat: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/E:/ergebnis_16.04.2024_09-15-18.docx"

Please pay more attention to detail. What exactly did you dd()? Did you get rid of url()? If you did, did you check the saveAs method in your TemplateProcessor? Does it maybe add the URL? You can [edit] your question and add any changes you made instead of the comments

I have now adjusted $outputPath like this: $outputPath = 'localhost/src/data/ergebnis_' . $timestamp . '.docx'; then I get the following error message: copy(localhost/src/data/ergebnis_16.04.2024_09-26-30.docx): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

With  $outputPath = public_path('template_output/Result_' . $timestamp . '.docx'); the code works but then it is saved in Laravel :(

Why localhost? Is that a folder on your filesystem? Most likely not. Try $outputPath = 'E:\ergebnis_' . $timestamp . '.docx'; Good luck
